# Libvlc - minimal files (functions) set for streaming out

Tags: streaming, desktop, libvlc

My application is for system administrators. One of the most needed features - is remote desktop monitoring. First way - is to grab screenshots and send them to admin. Second way - more interesting - grab desktop and stream it out over RTSP with libvlc. But it needs libvlccore and Plugins folder. Common size is over 68MB.
I'm sure that RTSP doesn't use all of plugins. Does anybody know how to build a single file with a minimal set of functions for streaming out (from vlc sources ofcourse)?